# Как разбросать элементы шапки по трём сторонам?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть шапка, в которой есть строковое меню (горизонтальное), логотип и одна кнопка. Нужно, чтобы строковое меню было посередине, логотип слева, а кнопка справа.
Это все в одном блоке `<div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, хотел ли автор именно это, но я б ответил так же, лови плюс

Comment: Добавил вариант с `grid`. Ждал что ты добавишь, но не дождался )

Answer (score 5):

Тут можно сделать это несколькими способами. Первый как написал в своем ответе @meine - используя `flexbox`, следующий способ используя `grid`, также можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями, используя для этого к примеру тот же Bootstrap 4.
Вот вариант с `grid`:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'logo grid-menu button'; 
  align-content: center;
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color:#b1db08;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}
.grid-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: grid-menu;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  align-content: center;
}
.menu-item {
  background-color: #d7db08;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.button {
  grid-area: button;
}
.bt {
  padding: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="logo"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i></div>
  <div class="grid-menu">
    <div class="menu-item">Главная</div>
    <div class="menu-item">Новости</div>
    <div class="menu-item">О нас</div>  
    <div class="menu-item">Контакты</div>
    <div class="menu-item">Акции</div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="bt">Click</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Сильно со стилями не игрался, главное показать принцип, остальное дело вкуса.

Comment: Лови плюсик :-)